# Can I use apply family to replace the for loop?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(4286)
n <- 4
k <- 5
V <- sample(seq(4), size=k, replace=TRUE)
M <- matrix(rnorm(n*k), ncol=k)
X <- M
for(i in seq(n)){
    X[i,] <- round(M[i,]/V, 2)
}
```

How can I use `apply` family to do the same job above instead of using `for` loop?

Comment: `round(M/matrix(rep(V, NROW(M)), nrow = NROW(M), byrow = TRUE), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the apply equivalent. The results need to be transposed by default.

```
t(apply(M, 1, function(x) round(x/V, 2)))
```